# NoMethodError in Users#paypal_verification

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, paypal, parameters, controller

Im getting this error 
I get this error when I load the page.  Why could this be happening? does this have to do with user?? my url is http://localhost:3000/users/4/paypal_verification

**error log:**

```html
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `verifications' for #<Array:0x007ffc8e78f590>):
    1: <%= form_for([@user, @user.verifications.new]) do |f| %>
    2:  <%= f.email_field :paypal_email, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Paypal Email", id: 'Pemail' %>
    3: <%= f.text_field :paypal_firstname, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Paypal FirstName", id: 'PfirstName' %>
    4: <%= f.text_field :paypal_lastname, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Paypal LastName", id: 'PlastName' %>
  app/views/users/paypal_verification.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users_paypal_verification_html_erb___3907504954927390416_70361349334300'
```

**users controller**

```rails
def index

        @search = User.ransack(params[:q])
        @user = @search.result.order("created_at DESC").to_a.uniq

        @country = User.uniq.pluck(:country)
        @city = User.uniq.pluck(:city)
        @school = User.uniq.pluck(:school)
        @major = User.uniq.pluck(:major)


        @results = @search.result
        @arrUsers = @results.to_a

        @revisers = Reviser.all

    end

def paypal_verification

    @user.find(params[:user_id])
end



    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @users = User.all
        @revisers = Reviser.all


    end
```

**verification controller**

```rails
def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @verification = current_user.verifications.create(verification_params)
    redirect_to @user.edit

    if @verification 

            require 'paypal-sdk-adaptiveaccounts'
@api = PayPal::SDK::AdaptiveAccounts::API.new( :device_ipaddress => "127.0.0.1" )

# Build request object
@get_verified_status = @api.build_get_verified_status({
  :emailAddress => "<%= current_user.paypal_email %>",
  :matchCriteria => "NAME",
  :firstName => "<%= current_user.paypal_firstname %>",
  :lastName => "<%= current_user.paypal_lastname %>" })

# Make API call & get response
@get_verified_status_response = @api.get_verified_status(@get_verified_status)

# Access Response
if @get_verified_status_response.success?
  @get_verified_status_response.accountStatus
  @get_verified_status_response.countryCode
  @get_verified_status_response.userInfo
else
  @get_verified_status_response.error
end

      params.permit!
    status = params[:accountStatus]

verification = Verification.find(params[:paypal_email])

if status == "VERIFIED"
    verification.update_attributes paypal_verified: true
else 
    verification.update_attributes paypal_verified: false
    verification.destroy
end
else
    redirect_to @user.edit
end
    end



    private
        def verification_params
            params.require(:verification).permit(:user_id, :paypal_firstname, :paypal_lastname, :paypal_email, :paypal_verified)
        end
```

**paypal_verification html**

```html
<div>
 <h>Hello</h>
<%= form_for([@user, @user.verifications.new]) do |f| %>
 <%= f.email_field :paypal_email, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Paypal Email", id: 'Pemail' %>
<%= f.text_field :paypal_firstname, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Paypal FirstName", id: 'PfirstName' %>
<%= f.text_field :paypal_lastname, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Paypal LastName", id: 'PlastName' %>
<%= f.text_field :paypal_verified, :class => 'form-control', id: 'Pverified'%>

<%= f.submit "verify", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

```rails
 devise_for :users ,
       :path => '' ,
       :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :edit => 'profile'},
       :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth_callbacks',
                :registrations => 'registrations'
              }


 resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do

 end
 resources :revisers
 resources :photos
 resources :pages

 #make sure to change this to user!!! instead of reservations!!!
resources :reviser do
  resources :reservations, only: [:create]
end


resources :user do
  resources :verifications, only: [:create]
end


get '/users/:id/paypal_verification' => 'users#paypal_verification'
```

Comment: The error shows that you're calling `verifications` on an array. I'd say you should check the value of your `@user`. If you're not able to figure it out, you should post your routes.rb and your complete users_controller especially the paypal_verification action.

Comment: I edited my post and im also using devise!! not sure if that changes things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error could be coming from your `set_user` method in your `UsersController`, even though you've not shown it above.

Could you change it to be:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, except: [:index]

  ... your other actions here

  def paypal_verification
   @verification = @user.verifications.new
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

In your views/users/paypal_verification.html.erb, you could then have:

```
<div>
    <h>Hello</h>
<%= form_for([@user, @verification]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.email_field :paypal_email, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Paypal Email", id: 'Pemail' %>
<%= f.text_field :paypal_firstname, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Paypal FirstName", id: 'PfirstName' %>
<%= f.text_field :paypal_lastname, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Paypal LastName", id: 'PlastName' %>
<%= f.text_field :paypal_verified, :class => 'form-control', id: 'Pverified'%>

<%= f.submit "verify", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Let me know if that works.